# Clean up project: Office 365

Tags: discussion, retag-request, clean-up, tag-synonyms

I draw your attention to the tag [office-365](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-365).

There seems to be a bit of confusion on what this tag is for. Granted, the description isn't great, but that's fairly easily remedied.

A goodly number of the questions are actually about **Office Online** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Online)), previously known as *Office Web Apps*. It offers web-based versions of Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and OneNote, as well as Outlook.com and its related *People* and *Calendar*, in addition to OneDrive. All of these, being web apps, are within this site's bailiwick. (There is a private server version of these, and the configuration of that would be off-topic here, but the use of the apps would be fine.)

**Office 365** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_365)), however, is a subscription suite for Microsoft Office products that allows for those software packages to save and work with information "in the cloud" (whether hosted by Microsoft or privately). Where Microsoft Word saves its data, whether locally, on a network, or in the cloud, doesn't make much difference; it's off-topic here and should to go [Super User](http://superuser.com). To confuse matters, Office 365 also offers access to *Office Online* and *Outlook on the Web*, which would be on topic here.

So, this is what I'm proposing:

- creation of [office-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-online); make [office-web-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-web-apps) a synonym; update the tag wiki. **Done**.
- creation of [word-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-online), [excel-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel-online), and [outlook-on-the-web](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook-on-the-web) (with good tag wikis). **Done** (*Good tag wikis?*)
- re-tagging questions tagged [office-365](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-365) to [word-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-online), [excel-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel-online), and/or [outlook-on-the-web](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook-on-the-web) depending on what topic they're covering
- re-tag any questions that are about the suite itself to [office-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-online)
- by this time, most [office-365](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-365) questions should be gone; if there are any that are about Office 365 and are still on-topic, fine, otherwise re-tag as appropriate
- check that existing questions tagged [microsoft-word](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word), [microsoft-excel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel), and [outlook-web-access](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook-web-access) shouldn't instead be tagged [word-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-online), [excel-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel-online), and [outlook-on-the-web](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook-on-the-web) respectively
- <del>clean up the [office](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office), which has no guidance and is too generic to be a tag. Perhaps make it a synonym of [office-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-online)</del>

We already have tags for [onedrive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onedrive), [onenote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onenote), [sharepoint](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint), and [outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com), although their wikis could probably use some polish. When making/updating these tag wikis, be sure to cross-reference other, related tags. It would also be good to point people toward Super User for their normal Office software related questions.

Comment: Sounds good. At first, the list of bullets looked overwhelming, but then I noticed it's just 30 questions in [tag:office-365] plus 13 questions in [tag:office], and maybe 11 in [tag:office-web-apps] (if they need retagging). Count me in.

Comment: There is a bunch to do, but we should do it in small batches so as not to overwhelm the front page. Of course, fix other issues you find on the post and vote-to-close those that are out of scope.

Comment: I think this is definitely a good idea, I'd love to help out but my rep is currently too low, and my skill-set too narrow to answer many questions and quickly raise it.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos: People with low reputation can still help with cleanup efforts. Suggested edits are almost as helpful, and can be a good way to get some extra reputation points. Just be sure to only do a little bit at a time (so as not to flood the front page) and fix _all_ the obvious problems with a post, not just the tags.

Comment: Am I correct that downvotes cost 1 rep? And if so, why?

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos: That's rather a separate question. Lots of details here: [If downvoting is so important, why does it cost reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62130/if-downvoting-is-so-important-why-does-it-cost-reputation)

Comment: @pnuts: I believe the work is still in progress.