# Please make [office-web-apps] a synonym of [office-online]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

(This is related to: [Clean up project: Office 365](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3952/clean-up-project-office-365))

*Office Web Apps* is an old name for what has now become *Office Online*.

Please make [office-web-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-web-apps) a synonym of [office-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-online) and merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requested merge has now been done